# Change code from using heap to using the stack

Tags: c++

Have the following two code snippets which use the heap.  I need to change to use the stack.

```
  prof_pair_class* ptr_prof_pair = (new prof_pair_class(
        aa_profile
      , bb_profile
      , aa_type
      , bb_type
      ));
```

and

```
   aa_plan = new nPlan(
         aa_prof_analysis
         , prm_segment_data.aa_field.target_gqi
         , prm_segment_data.aa_field.aa_response
         , prm_segment_data.aa.user_type
         );
```

Comment: Very unclear what you are asking. Are you simply asking how to declare a local variable in C++? or is there some actual problem that you don't know how to solve without using heap-allocated objects?

Comment: At first blush, this is simply a matter of replacing `prof_pair_class *ptr_prof_pair = new prof_pair_class(...)` with `prof_pair_class prof_pair{...}` (in C++ 11). But you likely meant to ask something else...

Comment: No such thing as a heap/stack in C++. There is dynamically storage duration objects (created via new); is that what you mean. As an alternative you can use static or automatic storage duration objects.

Comment: Solomon Slow, the code snippets are two different examples of code that are using heap-allocated objects.  So, correct, I am looking for answer for these two examples using the stack instead of the heap.

Comment: @MartinYork "heap" is easier to say than "dynamic storage duration," and virtually every programmer knows what it means. Ditto "stack" vs. "automatic storage duration."

Comment: @SolomonSlow Unfortunately they are inaccurate terms when it comes to C++. How do you describe an automatic member of an object that was dynamically created using this vernacular? In this scenario you have an automatic object on the "heap" while your interpretation is that automatic variables are always on the "stack". Now I am happy to say automatic/dynamic rather than "automatic storage duration object", But the terms heap and stack are meaningless because of their inaccuracy in describing the object.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Now the terms heap/stack work perfectly for Java (as this is the language the made this terms popular for objects). This is because Java does not have the same concept of lifespan that C++ does (in fact Java allows object resurrection in destructor a wild and beautiful idea). But lifespan in C++ is highly described and a very integral part of the language. But using terms from one language in a completely different language never really translates well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are four types of objects in C++ Automatic/Static/Dynamic/Thread storage duration objects.

The two I will discuss here are Automatic and Dynamic.

#### Dynamic Storage Duration

These objects are created via `new` and their lifespan ends when passed to `delete` (or their array equivalents).

```
Type*  val = new Type(<param>);  // Object created here.
                                 // Will live until delete is called on val
                                 // If you forget or there is a bug that misses the delete.
                                 // the object will be leaked.
```

In modern C++ it is rare to see naked new/delete as memory management is usually done via containers or smart pointers (this prevents manual memory management that is the bane of C applications).

#### Automatic Storage Duration

These objects are created in the current local scope (at the point of declaration) and their lifespan ends when control exits the current scope.

```
{
    Type  val(<param>);   // declared here
    // STUFF
}                         // end of scope here.
                          // The object's lifespan ends here and
                          // the object is automatically destroyed.
```

#### Inside Objects

Both automatic and dynamic objects can live inside class(s). For dynamic objects nothing changes, but the use of constructors and destructors help to correctly manage the lifespan of the pointer (if done correctly (see rule of five)).

But for automatic variables the scope of the variable becomes the lifespan of the object they are in. If the parent is an automatic object then when the parent leaves scope and its lifespan ends so does the children members. If the parent is dynamic then the children members scope ends when the parent is passed to `delete`.

```
class X
{
    Y  val;   // The scope of the automatic member val is X
};               // If the parent object is alive then val is alive.

{
    X  tmp;
}            // tmp goes out of scope. Then tmp is destroyed as is tmp.val

X* ptr = new X;  // the object pointed at by ptr lives until it is deleted.
                 // So its member val will live until the parent is deleted.
```

#### In your case.

TO convert your object from Dynamic to automatic simply stop using `new`.

```
// declare a dynamic variable.
prof_pair_class* ptr_prof_pair = new prof_pair_class(
        aa_profile
      , bb_profile
      , aa_type
      , bb_type
      );

{
    // declare an automatic variable.
    prof_pair_class prof_pair(
            aa_profile
          , bb_profile
          , aa_type
          , bb_type
          );
}
```

#### Passing to function:

If your original function called looked like this:

```
AAAAA_Facade::process_profile_dta(prof_pair_class,
                                  &fg_prof_analysis,
                                  &gf_prof_analysis
                                 );
```

Then you will need to change the call to look like this.

```
AAAAA_Facade::process_profile_dta(&prof_pair,        // Add the & here.
                                  &fg_prof_analysis,
                                  &gf_prof_analysis
                                 );
```

The reason is that the function is expecting a pointer to `prof_pair_class`. SO the expected type is `prof_pair_class*`. The type of the automatic variable is `prof_pair_class` so we need to convert the object into a pointer by using the address operator `&`.

Note: There is a danger to doing this. If the function is expecting a dynamically allocated object and you pass the address of an automatic object then things can go seriously wrong when the function calls delete on your pointer. So you should make sure the function is not expecting you to pass an owned ptr.

If you have any control over the interface of `process_profile_dta()` I would change it. Rather than accepting pointers it should accept references to the object (assuming that it is not taking ownership of the objects passed).

```
namespace AAAAA_Facade
{
    // Pass values by reference.
    // This allows you to access the original objects.
    // But does not imply any ownership transfer
    void process_profile_dta(prof_pair_class&        prof_pair,
                             fg_prof_analysis_class& fg_prof_analysis,
                             gf_prof_analysis_class& gf_prof_analysis
                            );
}
```

Comment: Martin, yes, excellent explanation of memory types and usage.  I did remove new but the receive error on the function call that immediately follows... I assume because it is still using the ptr.   Code is as follows:   AAAAA_Facade::process_profile_dta(
      ptr_hdgp_prof_pair
      , &fg_prof_analysis  // output parameter
      , &gf_prof_analysis  // output parameter
      );

Comment: @66chawger That's probably because the function is expecting a different type. Remember `Type` and `Type*` are not the same and C++ is a statically typed language where the parameters passed to a function must match the type of the parameters passed. Now you can can convert an object to a pointer by taking its address (this will give you the original pointer type). But the danger here is if the function you called is expecting a dynamically allocated object and it calls delete on the passed pointer you are in big trouble. (This is why modern C++ interfaces don't use pointers a lot).

Comment: PS. You should add the information in the comment to the original question. It would help people a lot to understand the context of the question.

Comment: Martin, yes, it is expecting the Type*, however, as you mentioned the delete for the pointer doesn't occur in that called function, it occurs at the end of the calling function which I had commented out.

Comment: Will do!  sry about that.

Comment: @66chawger Added some notes about how to improve `process_profile_dta()`

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways I can think of. The easiest is

```
 prof_pair_class ptr_prof_pair(
      aa_profile
    , bb_profile
    , aa_type
    , bb_type
    );
```

The hard way is to us a custom allocator that calls alloca along with a smart pointer.

Comment: Out of general curiosity, for what type of situation would you ever need to do the latter? That seems like an overly-complicated solution to declaring an object on the stack.

Comment: The alloca method is used on systems that support it when the amount of data needed is variable—not the case here.

Comment: Interesting. After looking it up, it seems to be primarily a Linux thing; I have to look into that more. Thanks for the input.

Comment: user3344003, I receive error Error 20 error C2664: 'SMARTGrind_Facade::process_profile_dta' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'prof_pair_class' to 'prof_pair_class *'  for the code immediately following as follows:          AA_Facade::process_profile_dta(
      ptr_hdgp_prof_pair
      , &fg_prof_analysis  // output parameter
      , &gf_prof_analysis  // output parameter
      );